# JDBC update insertion will hangs or waits

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

```
 PreparedStatement ps;
 boolean usage = exeUpdate("insert into usage values(null,'" + record[1] + "','" + record[2] + "')");
 result = exeQuery("select id from usage where src ='" + record[1] + "' and dst='" + record[2] + "'");

 String id = "";
 while (result.next()) {
      id = result.getString("id");
 }     
 //boolean text = exeUpdate("insert into text values('" + id + "',to_timestamp('" + record[3] + "','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'" + record[4] + "')");
             ps=connection.prepareStatement("insert into text  values(?,to_timestamp(?,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),?)");
 //            //System.out.println("pare");
             ps.setString(1, id);
             ps.setString(2, record[3]);
             ps.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(record[4]));
             ps.executeUpdate();
             ps.close();
```

I have a file with entries to read for recording into my database.
I extract information from each line to make an insertion.

```
public static boolean exeUpdate(String query) {
    try {
        s.executeUpdate(query);
        System.out.println("Successfully updated!");
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JogWireless.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("Sorry, Update unsuccessful!");
    }
    return false;
}
```

I closed connection and statement after reading in all files. 
I am guessing there is a deadlock issue which results in the wait, I have tried preparedStatement and the problem still exist. I can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: Have you verified auto-commit is on or that you are calling `commit()`?

Comment: I think it's auto-commit.

Comment: *Never* build a query string by concatenating `String`s, some of which are program inputs.  It is both unsafe and subject to breakage.  Use a `PreparedStatement` instead.  Whether that solves the problem you are presently experiencing is entirely beside the point.

Comment: You don't have to guess whether the connection is in autoCommit mode -- use `Connection.getAutoCommit()` to find out for sure.

Comment: If the problem is that `s.executeUpdate(query)` hangs, then how can it be that you "closed connection and statement after reading in all files"?  Do you have multiple threads involved?

Comment: Thanks! It's saying true.

Comment: I was trying to say that executeUpdate(query) is visited multiple times because there are multiple entries in the file. The first time it can execute, the second time just hangs there. It's not multi-thread.

Comment: I don't see anything in what you presented that explains the problem.  It's a bit suspicious that you ignore the return value of `exeUpdate()`, but even if that method fails, there's no reason to think that would cause subsequent updates to hang.  We might be able to help you better if you presented a [mcve].  You might be able to help yourself by running the program in a debugger to verify that it in fact does hang where you think it does, and to clarify the circumstances.

Comment: Solved the problem by writing a procedure and calling it. Still don't know why executeUpdate won't work. But it's working fine now. Thanks!